# Droid Explorer is unable to browse device

Tags: connection-issues, droid-explorer

I love the idea of being able to browse root directories on my laptop.

But I can't for the life of me get droid explore to work, I have a note 4 (rooted of course), I am running stock Sammy ROM, I have installed adbd insecure on my device and I can access root via adb, but I cannot do anything with this software.  I also have busybox installed to `/xbin`.

When I click connect device, my device does show up, but when I click on said device, the application grays out and i cannot click anything other than min/max or close. It is the same with a rooted Samsung nexus that i have, running CM11. Any input would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: i am running 64bit win 7 and I have tried reinstalling the software twice.

Comment: I just saw the second part that you have the same issue with the device running CM11. This sounds more like something that I would consider a bug. If you could file the bug on the [Issue Tracker](https://de.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic). Sounds like the application is locking up for some reason. In the bug, please provide as much info as possible. OS, system specs (like memory, processor), android sdk version, phone info. Thanks. I am going to vote to close this, as I do not think there is any answer that would solve it, unless I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of Droid Explorer*

Without knowing the exact version of the SDK platform-tools you have installed (but I will assume the latest), I think the problem is with the Android SDK platform-tools.

Droid Explorer uses a feature in ADB called 'status-window' to keep track of the connection state of the devices. In the latest version (rev. 23), they removed this feature.

You can manually download an older version of the platform-tools and put them in your SDK directory:

- Download rev. 21 of the platform-tools from [platform-tools_r21-windows.zip](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r21-windows.zip)
- Rename the `platform-tools` directory in your SDK to `platform-tools-23`
- Extract the zip file, downloaded previously, to the root of your SDK directory. It contains the `platform-tools` directory in the zip.

This will be corrected in the next version of Droid Explorer so it will again work with the latest SDK. I have been working on multiple ways to replace the functionality that was removed in the latest revision of the platform-tools. Once I am happy with how it functions and am confident that it is stable, I will release an update.