# Remove old device added by DroidExplorer from Windows

Tags: windows, droid-explorer

I had my old Kindle connected to my PC, and it showed a device in the "This PC" screen along with all my Hard Drives. Double-clicking it opens DroidExplorer and my device if connected. However, it doesn't open my new device (obviously) and sits there doing nothing and never goes away.

How can I remove that from the list? Is it listed as an "Android Adapter USB Device" under Device Manager?

For others who see this, I just want to remove the icon that DroidExplorer has added. This is what it looks like:

> [image]

Comment: I believe you can right click on it and remove. Then after that re-plugin your device and it should work.

Comment: I tried that, Right Clicking the item has two options, Create Shortcut and Open.

Comment: It looks like this might be the same issue as in [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120495/1465), try the answer suggested there.

Comment: @MatthewRead I appreciate the help, but I am unsure if that would help. I don't even have the device to browse anymore, that's not what I am trying to do. I want to remove the Icon it has placed in my "My PC" / "This PC" section of my computer. It's in the screenshot I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of Droid Explorer*

---

From the [Droid Explorer FAQ](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/wiki/FAQ):

**Q.** I have a "phantom" device in Windows Explorer that shows as connected, but it isn't.

**A.** We are not yet sure what causes the rare instance of a "phantom" device. But here is how you can manually remove it.

- Open Registry Editor:

  - WIN+R
  - Type regedit, hit enter
- Search HKEYCLASSESROOT\CLSID for the value of the "phantom" device ID. This is the name under the icon in explorer
- The parent key to the device ID will be a GUID like {4aadfc55-0657-4b44-9f58-a0fca98fcb31}, for example. Remember this, write it down or paste it in to notepad.
- Delete the key "HKEYCLASSESROOT\CLSID{4aadfc55-0657-4b44-9f58-a0fca98fcb31} - replace the GUID with the GUID assigned to your "phantom" device
- Navigate to HKEYLOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\
- You will see another key named the GUID to your "phantom" device, delete this key as well.

Comment: Also, as an added bonus, I found an easy way to find all the keys. So when I clicked the device, on the right I have File Details on, and saw what looked like the GUID you shown, so I searched that key in the Registry and found them easily. So I just hit Ctrl + F in the Registry and searched the key that it shown me. https://i.imgur.com/nE2Y29R.png 

Feel free to use that image if you want. Also, I searched the second key, not the first one.